Begining a QPainter on a QPrinter in a background thread freezes the entire application
In my Qt app, I have a relatively large QGraphicsScene, and rendering it into a QPrinter takes a couple of seconds and making the app unresponsive. Therefore, I decided to render the scene in a background thread, However issuing QPainter::begin() on a QPrinter that points to a virtual printer (i.e. printers that write to a PDF file) in a background thread causes the entire application to freeze and no PDF file is generated.
I believe QPainter::begin() for virtual printers requires opening a file dialog to obtain the PDF file name. Since this call occurs in a background thread, it cannot open the file dialog, leading to a deadlock in the entire application.
Here is a minimal and complete example illustrating the problem:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QThread
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter


class RenderThread(QThread):
    scene: QGraphicsScene
    printer: QPrinter

    def __init__(self, scene: QGraphicsScene, printer: QPrinter, parent: QObject) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.scene = scene
        self.printer = printer

    def run(self) -> None:
        painter = QPainter(self.printer)
        self.scene.render(painter)


class Window(QWidget):
    scene: QGraphicsScene
    printer: QPrinter
    renderer: RenderThread

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addEllipse(5, 5, 50, 50)
        self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
        self.renderer = RenderThread(self.scene, self.printer, self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QPushButton("Print")
        layout.addWidget(button, 0, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        button.clicked.connect(self.renderer.start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread. Any Qt class that isn't explicitly documented as thread-safe should not be accessed from a different thread. A couple of seconds isn't a big deal. Just show a busy indicator of some kind so the user knows what is happening.
